# Mint - disk is full (prevents login)

Tags: linux-mint, login, disk

I had 0 bytes free and even when I deleted something the number of free bytes stayed still zero. So I tried to restart it and I can't login now. I tried console <kbd>Ctrl+Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, but I don't know login. I wrote the name that is normally displayed above the password, but it is wrong. What should I do?

Comment: You say "deleted something", do you mean a file? Is it available _disk space_ that is zero.  The word "memory" is mostly used to refer to RAM memory.

Comment: Yes, I ment file.

Comment: And by "memory", do you mean "disk space"?

Comment: yes I mean disk place. It is similar problem to https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=251317

Comment: If you are able to access the console using live disk, could you check for the files consuming most space `du -csh *` and also logs which may be compressed to make some space.

Comment: I am not able to log in the console.

Comment: It writes Login incorrect

Comment: Have you got a 'live disk', a bootable DVD disk or USB pendrive or memory card? In that case boot into it and from there search for and remove files, that you don't need. That way you can get enough free drive space for your Mint to work again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Make a LiveUSB](https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/burn.html) on another machine

Boot from that LiveUSB on your PC.

Access your boot drive, whether SSD or HDD (makes no difference).

Either delete files you don't need, or move them to another drive (such as a USB or external SSD or HDD).

After this problem is resolved, you may wish to consider the use of [tmpreaper](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/tmpreaper.8.html) or equivalent to delete temp files between reboots, and also a method to monitor file space available (I use [conky](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/conky.1.html) on my desktop for this).